# How to join tables on different databases from different servers

Tags: laravel, mariadb, laravel-6

[Laravel 6]

I'm trying to join 2 tables from different server databases.

Here's the database configuration :

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db1'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'table1'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],

'external' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('EXTERNAL_HOST', '123.456.789.2'),
    'port' => env('EXTERNAL_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('EXTERNAL_DATABASE', 'db2'),
    'username' => env('EXTERNAL_USERNAME', 'table2'),
    'password' => env('EXTERNAL_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'unix_socket' => env('EXTERNAL_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

Here's the query :

```
return $query->join('db2.table2', function($join) {
    $join->on('table1.gateway', '=', 'db2.table2.gateway');
    $join->on('table1.prefixlen', '=', 'db2.table2.prefixlen');
    $join->on('table1.vlan', '=', 'db2.table2.vlan');
})->select('table1.*');
```

But I received this error message :

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db2.table2' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from table1 inner join db2.table2 on table1.gateway = db2.table2.gateway and table1.prefixlen = db2.table2.prefixlen and table1.vlan = db2.table2.vlan)
```

I've tried googling around in the last couple days, but I couldn't figure out the right way to do it.

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: I dont think this is possible. To join tables on 2 different servers.

Comment: Agree, 3 conclusions I have for now :
1. use Federated Engine on the remote database, based on this [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)
2. use eager loading
3. Create a new table and then import data from the remote table to it, I'm using this approach right now

Comment: I know it is possible to set a model's `$connection`So one model can point to db A and the other to db B and these can go over multiple servers. I cannot test it right now as i do not have a 2nd db setup, but I know it should work if you make relationships between the 2 models and use `eager loading` like @budiantoip said(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)